# Alternative to AWS EventBridge Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

Is there an alternative to EventBridge Rule that can filter Cloudtrail events? The current pattern character limit is not sufficient for my use case.

I use EventBridge Rules to filter S3 data events with ‘anything-but’ acting as an allowlist of IAM roles that are expected to access the bucket. However, that allowlist has grown big enough to exceed the 2048 character limit for Rule pattern. I know that I could extend the limit to 4096 but that would be just pushing back the problem until it hits the new limit. Is there anything else I could use in this case?